# SVM object based classification QGIS with Orfeo Toolbox. Model outputs incorrect/ invalid

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-classification

I am trying to run an SVM object based classification on QGIS with Orfeo Toolbox. I have 5x Spectral Tif images of bands; blue,Green, red, Infra-red and Rededge, these were generated from a UAV survey using a multi-spectral camera.

My 'model' outputs from the training classification through 'Train images classifier' delivers multiple files such as shp. prj. dbf. etc.. but no singular model file. I have been thus far unsuccessful in running the classification. I have tried using all 5 spectral bands, then also just NDVI as well. Does anyone know how to save just one model file? or know where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The multi-file output you describe is the format of a [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). A single shapefile is made up of 3 or more separate files with the same name but different file extensions. (Always .shp, .shx and .dbf. Sometimes .prj, .shp.xml, .sbn, and others.)

If you want a single file output, choose a different output format where a single layer is only one file, such as [geopackage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoPackage).

See also: http://switchfromshapefile.org/ for information about other file formats (and opinions about why shapefiles are terrible).